# Excel Split Single Column Into Multiple Columns Based on Header Rows

Tags: excel, split, multiple-columns

I have an excel file that contains data exported from LTSpice simulations. There are 280 different runs however the data is exported as two columns (time and voltage) with a run cell at the start of a new run. The number of data points in each run varies. Looks something like this:

```
Run 1/280
Time1        Voltage1
Time2        Voltage2
Run 2/280
Time1        Voltage1
Time2        Voltage2
Time3        Voltage3
Run 3/280
```

I would like to have the run cells as row and the time and voltage columns beneath them.

```
Run 1/280                Run 2/280                Run 3/280
Time1        Voltage1    Time1        Voltage1
Time2        Voltage2    Time2        Voltage2
                         Time3        Voltage3
```

I haven't found an easy way to do this yet, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA...

For each row of your input list, you need to identify its type (`Run x/xxx` header or `terminal, voltage` pair) and the row and pair of columns in the output where this input row belongs.

In the picture below, columns `A` and `B` perform this task. Column `A` identifies the output column pair and `B` the output row, where row 0 indicates the header row of the output.

The header row of the output utilises the fact that if an `array` is sorted in ascending order and has repeated values then `MATCH(x,array,0)` finds the index of the **first** element in `array` equal to x. The cumbersome repetition of the `SUMPRODUCT` term in the formulae for the other rows is necesssary for the following reason. If there is no matching pair in columns `A` and `B` to the current output row and column pair number then the `SUMPRODUCT` delivers 0 and, unfortunately, the `INDEX(array,SUMPRODUCT())` term evaluates to `INDEX(array,0)` which delivers the first element of `array` (*) - which is not what is wanted.

[image]

You obviously need sufficient helper values in `row 1` and `column E` of the worksheet in the output area - the maximum values of columns `B` and `A`, respectively determine the requirements. Oversizing the output (as the picture has done) is not a problem as the formulae in any redundant positions simply evaluate to `""`.

(*) In fact, for a single column `array` the formula `=INDEX(array,0)` evaluates to the `array` itself. When used as cell formula (rather than being used as an array formula across a range of cells) formula simply picks the first value from `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Sub SplitToColumns()
    ' 16 Sep 2017

    Dim WsS As Worksheet                    ' S = "Source"
    Dim WsD As Worksheet                    ' D = "Destination"
    Dim WsDName As String
    Dim RunId As String                     ' first word in "Run 1/280"
    Dim RowId As Variant                    ' value in WsS.Column(A)
    Dim Rl As Long                          ' last row (WsS)
    Dim Rs As Long, Rd As Long              ' row numbers
    Dim Cd As Long                          ' column (WsD)

    WsDName = "RemoteMan"                   ' change to a valid tab name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WsD = Worksheets(WsDName)
    If Err Then
        ' create WsD if it doesn't exist:
        Set WsD = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        WsD.Name = WsDName
        Cd = -1
    Else
        ' continue adding new data to the right of existing,
        With WsD.UsedRange
            Cd = .Columns.Count - 1
            If Cd = 1 And .Rows.Count = 1 Then Cd = -1
        End With
    End If

    Set WsS = Worksheets("Remote")          ' change to a valid tab name
    With WsS
        ' presume "Run" & Time in column A, Voltage in Column B
        ' presume: no blank rows
        Rl = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        RunId = .Cells(2, 1).Value          ' row 2 must have the RunId
        RunId = Left(RunId, InStr(RunId, " ") - 1)
        For Rs = 2 To Rl                    ' assume data start in row 2 (A1 may not be blank!)
            RowId = .Cells(Rs, "A").Value
            If InStr(1, RowId, RunId, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                Rd = 1                      ' first row to use in WsD
                Cd = Cd + 2                 ' determine next columns
            End If
            WsD.Cells(Rd, Cd).Value = RowId
            WsD.Cells(Rd, Cd + 1).Value = .Cells(Rs, "B").Value
            Rd = Rd + 1                     ' next row to use
        Next Rs
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```